# How much classes for exceptions

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

What's the usual way to create & handle exceptions in c++?

```
class CannotRead : public runtime_exception { ... }
class CannotParse : public runtime_exception { ... }

...
throw CannotRead();
...
```

or

```
...
throw runtime_error("cannot read");
...
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this in C++?

Links to articles comparing both approaches would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Using explicit exception classes means you can have more explicit error handling. If all you get is a generic `runtime_error` you really can't handle specific exceptions in a way that fits that exception better.

Comment: Just use `std::runtime_exception` and give it an appropriate error message. I wouldn't create an extra exception for each and every case.

Comment: I recommend: None besides the standard exceptions - In other words, have as less as possible. (also derive from std::exception)

Comment: Both are idiomatic. Use the first if you need to pass specific information about the exception to complex handlers, the second to pass a simple message to a simple handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no cut and dry advice to give, but my personal rule of thumb is:

- throw `std::runtime_error` (or one of its siblings, as appropriate)
- until you find you need to distinguish at `catch`-time between your various exceptions, then start deepening the inheritance heirarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, as others have mentioned in comments, you derive from `std::runtime_error` and overload the `what()` virtual method. As an exercise to the reader, a constructor can also be written to capture the exception message. [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_exceptions_handling.htm) website provided the following code (although I modified it slightly to reflect the `std::runtime_error` change).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class MyException : public std::runtime_error
{       
    const char * what () const throw () { 
        return "C++ Exception";
    }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        throw MyException();
    } catch(MyException& e) {
        std::cout << "MyException caught" << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch(std::exception& e) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better to derive `runtime_error` (or one of its siblings) than `exception`.